# Query for selecting Itemnumber from table?

Tags: sql

I have Two Tables 1.Inventtable and 2.Texttable

1.[image]

and next table is

2.[image]

I need to select the itemnumbers from second table where ID!=2 and filename =etable in Inventtable.how to write the query for this

Comment: is there any common field between those two tables

Comment: try this select t.itemNumber 
from Inventtable i 
inner join Texttable it on it.itemNumber=i.Refkey
where i.ID<>2 and i.filename=etable

Comment: @swetha yes ..itemnumber and refkey are common

Comment: Yes Thanks @swetha ...Nice Working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query (for SQL Server):

```
select *
from Inventtable i 
inner join Texttable t on t.itemNumber=i.Refkey
where i.ID<>2 and i.filename='etable'
```

Comment: hi..I have another problem noticed today .with this query it also takes the data with containing ID 2.why like this?

Comment: @user2318361 It shouldn't. Can you create SQLFiddler?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct itemNumber from Inventtable join Texttable on itemNumber=Refkey
where ID != 2 and filename='etable'
```